# Evaluation of SHAP outputs

Tags: evaluation, shap, xai

Am working on implementing XAI using SHAP library, the implementation is just fine but in case we want to prove that shap outputs are accurate and we eventually can trust them, is there any kind of metrics or how can we make sure that the values we get are truly the correct features contributions

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [reprex]

Comment: I think maybe this question is better suited for Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/